# подмена заголовков

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как можно сделать чтобы на лендинге надпись менялась в зависимости от запроса в поисковой системе. Нужно создавать отдельную страницу под каждый поисковый запрос или есть какой то скрипт? Конкретно необходима подмена станций метро. Пример: на запрос "Пиявки медведково" конкретная страница, при "Пиявки бабушкинская" страница, на которой в контактах будет адрес бабушкинской. Сейчас при таких запросах в яндексе выдает подобные страницы: 
[Ссылка 1](http://biofabrika-piyavok.ru/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE.php)
[Ссылка 2](http://biofabrika-piyavok.ru/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F.php)

Comment: Сейчас поисковые системы шифруют информацию по какому запросу переходит пользователь. В примере по ссылкам просто созданы (нагенерированы) отдельные страницы под каждую локацию. Можно пытаться определять геолокацию пользователя и выдавать ее в надписи. Если происходит подмена лучше выводить ее через скрипты, чтобы не было воспринято поисковыми системами как клоакинг.

Answer (score 0):

Пример получения ближайшей станции метро по геокоординатам

```
/**
* Получение ближайшего метро по координатам
*
* @param array - массив с координатами [долгота,  широта]
* @return bool | string - false или название ближайшего метро
*/
function getMetroNameByCoord($coord){
    $coord_str = implode(",", $coord);
    $url_get_metro = "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode={$coord_str}&kind=metro&format=json&results=1"; 
    $result = @file_get_contents($url_get_metro);
    // если произошла ошибка при отправке запроса или ответе сервера
    (!$result) return false;
    $result = json_decode($result);
    // если ни чего не нашлось
    if(count($result->response->GeoObjectCollection->featureMember) == 0) return false;
    return $result->response->GeoObjectCollection->featureMember[0]->GeoObject->name;
}
```

Comment: как это можно прикрутить к html?

Comment: Ну например заходит пользователь, определились его координаты ajax запрашивает название ближайшей станции и если получил ответ меняет заголовок "Лучшие пиявки" на "Пиявки ***"